# Multiple submit Button click problem?

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net, events, onclick

I have a form which inserts data in DB on Submit button click but the problem is when client click the button multiple times its sends multiple create requests means multiple button click events for the same time of same data, which must not be.

I tried to disable the button when client click the Submit button first time but after this it does not call server click event handler or not fire the server click event once it got disabled.

How to handle this multiple click problem..

I used the following code to disable the button

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function checkAuth(obj)
     {
         if(Page_ClientValidate("ValidationGroupName"))
            obj.disabled=true;      
     }
 </script>

        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
OnClick="btnSubmit_click" OnClientClick="checkAuth(this)" CssClass="FormButton" 
ValidationGroup="ValidationGroupName" />
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50426/preventing-accidental-double-clicking-on-a-button

Comment: With the recently-added code, this is no longer a duplicate (not that you had any way of knowing that).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not disable the button, just prevent the second submit.

this little script does the job but it assumes there is a postback at a certain moment.

```
var formhandler = function() {
   var submit, isSubmit = false;
   submit = function(){
                // flop and return false once by the use of operator order.
    return isSubmit != (isSubmit = true);
    };
    return {
       submit: submit
    };
}(); // <-- use direct invcation to keep the internal variables "static"
```

attach it by :

```
   document.forms[0].onsubmit = formhandler.submit;
```

or

```
   OnClientClick = "formhandler.submit()";
```

Comment: @Caspar Kleijne : Does this code work with `Imagebutton` or it requires a button with `submitBehaviour = true` .

I want to use this code with an image button which transfer money .Is this enough to prevent multiple clicks in the case the browser or the network hangs on , and the client keep clicking??

Comment: it works with any element that has the onsubmit eventhandler attached.

Answer (score 1):

Include a unique id in a `<input type="hidden">` field. Then on the server check if the request has already been processed.

As an ID you can generate a GUID. Then you just need some structure to collect currently valid IDs. For example a Dictionary. Then from time to time you can clear old IDs out of the structure, and of course remove it when it is used.

Comment: I'm tempted to go with this one, but could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is have some client side javascript which disables the button. Something similar to:

```
document.myform.mybutton.disabled  = true;
```

If you wrap this in a function, and set the `onClientClick` attribute of your button to fire this.  As soon as it gets clicked it is disabled - but still generates the request to the server.

The reason the event didnt fire the way you suggested above is likely because you disabled server side (not client side as is here)

Comment: One has to be careful when using this technique. For example if the request uses AJAX and fails due to connection problems the user ends up with a broken website. And there are other causes of multi sends(like refreshing the target page)

Comment: True - but this question doesn't have an AJAX tag

Comment: look into the question I added the code which I used to disable the button.